# use filter in angular directive to change collection in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, directive, angular-directive, angular-filters

I have the following directive to set the 10 most used languages in the **beginning of a select** and set a custom css class:

```
app.directive('sortTopLocales', function ($timeout) {

  // copied from angular-chosen (to get the array of ng-options)
  var NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP = /^\s*(.*?)(?:\s+as\s+(.*?))?(?:\s+group\s+by\s+(.*))?\s+for\s+(?:([\$\w][\$\w]*)|(?:\(\s*([\$\w][\$\w]*)\s*,\s*([\$\w][\$\w]*)\s*\)))\s+in\s+(.*?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+(.*?))?$/;

  var top10languages = ['en', 'zh', 'es', 'ja', 'pt', 'de', 'ar', 'fr', 'ru', 'ko'];
  var top10languagesReversed = top10languages.reverse();
  var cssClass = 'top10';

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (attrs.ngOptions) {
        var match = attrs.ngOptions.match(NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP);

        scope.$watchCollection(match[7], function(locales) {

          var alreadySorted = element.find('option.'+cssClass).length;

          if(angular.isUndefined(locales) || alreadySorted) { return; }

          var top10Index = 0;

          $timeout(function() {
            element.find('option.'+cssClass).removeClass(cssClass); // reset CSS class

            angular.forEach(top10languagesReversed, function(locale) {
              var index = locales.indexOf(locale);
              if(index !== -1) {
                locales.splice(index, 1); // removes it from the array
                locales.unshift(locale); // sets it at the beginning of the array
                var option = element.find('option[value=' + top10Index + ']');
                option.addClass(cssClass);

                top10Index++;
              }
            });
            console.log(scope.$eval(match[7])[0], locales[0]); 
            // without filter => 'en', 'en'
            // with filter => 'aa', 'en'
          });

        });
      }

    }
  };
});
```

It works as expected without filter, but when I use a filter in `ng-options` it doesn't:

working:

`ng-options="locale for locale in locales" // match[7] = 'locales'`

not working:

`ng-options="locale for locale in locales | orderBy" // match[7] = 'locales | orderBy'`

There is a different output of the changed array and the expression of $watchCollection.

```
scope.$eval(match[7])[0] // 'aa'
locales[0]               // 'en'
```

When I use the filter inside the directive code and not in the HTML the array isn't updated either.

So basically my question is: How do I update an **array with filter** changed in $watchCollection to use it in ng-options?